# Scala types/collections when interfacing with Java and vice versa

Tags: java, scala, jvm, scala-collections, scala-java-interop

When interfacing with a scala library in java, or a java library in scala, are there certain types or collections that don't map efficiently such that you have to perform "expensive" operations to perform a conversion?

e.g. memory wise you might have to hold 2 copies of a collection?

Answer (score 3):

Well, that depends on how you want to handle it - if you use the Java class's API from Scala or the other way around, there is no run-time overhead, but you'll pay a convenience cost.

When you use [JavaConversions](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.JavaConversions%24) to access Java collections through a Scala API or the other way around, you pay a small cost for the conversion (a Wrapper object is created), but the underlying collection is never copied.

You can inspect the code for all this [here](https://github.com/scala/scala/tree/v2.10.1/src/library/scala/collection/convert), as usual for the Scala standard library it's all very readable and easy to understand.